# SQL Query to Compare Counts of Certain Values In a Field

Tags: sql

I would love some help learning to write this type of query- my SQL is not great yet, and I'm trying to remedy the situation. Assuming I have a table similar to the one I have shown below:

```
| id | hotel | opinion |
|:---|:-----:| -------:|
|1   |hotelA |good     |
|2   |hotelA |good     |
|3   |hotelA |bad      |
|4   |hotelB |good     |
|5   |hotelB |bad      |
```

Desired Output:
hotelA

How could I write a query to print only those hotels where the opinion field had more occurrences of "good" then "bad"? Also, any resources for getting better at SQL are very welcome :-)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You also need to _specify_ the expected result. (Your sample data is properly formatted!)

Comment: Edited to specify the expected result! My thinking is that I need to select hotel where opinion="good" as one variable, select hotel where oponion="bad" as another, use COUNT on both of them, then do a > comparison. I just have no either how to even begin to structure a query like that, I've been doing Hackerrank SQL exercises but haven't hit anything this advanced yet.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
SELECT TOP 1 hotel
FROM hotels
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN opinion = 'good' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to group by hotel and only show the hotels with more good than bad

```
select hotel 
from hotels
group by hotel having sum(case when option = 'good' then 1 else -1 end) > 0
```